# How many times can I vote without being suspended because of voting irregularly?

Tags: discussion

It has happened for me in two other forums because I used my right to downvote one users' trivial questions which s/he had made in a short time. Most them were closed or downvoted by the others! As I am just about one month in SE and some users in those forums tried to close or delete all my questions one after one without any convincing comment or respond, I thought with myself how can it be a fairly judgment which they can suspend me because of using my right for downvote a user (only by this pretext that "the systems' algorithms shows it as a irregular voting") who has made more than 10 questions in one day but if s/he tries the same against all my questions and answers as I am a new user and have only 5 or 6 questions or answers, surely the system doesn't show anything wrong, there is no punishment for him/her? This special user has high scores and very easily closes my right questions with high votes and good answers and even s/he follows me in different forums and downvotes me or sends offending comments for me after making any question in the other forums. I asked it if there is a solution to defend of my rights as I find it a kind of discrimination against myself and a misusing of systematic rules against new users. This problem gives a chance to high score users to impose their ideas to a majority who are new users and easily it can change SE forums to mafia managing systems not a fairly system which can recognize what positive cooperation means.

P.S: It is a valid question for this forum as it is a general question to find how SE works about this special matter! This forum is one of them.

Comment: Persia, if you continue to cast downvotes against one user, always the same, you are considered a user that violate the rules and, as such, you are supposed to be banned forever, -1.

Answer (score 5):

My best guess would be that your actions were deemed to be inflamatory or being used as a personal assult on other users. I have gone through and deleted all of your comments on this question for that very reason. When you start using words that may be construed as a verbal attack on others or may be interpreted as inflamatory, then you are not doing much to make yourself appear to be a sincere and committed participant of this site. I can guarantee that if you have more downvotes than upvotes, or even more than 10% of your total votes are downvotes, you are very likely to have your account suspended.

The use of a vote is NOT a weapon or tool that you can use to "get even" with someone. It should ONLY be used to reflect how well you think the question was answered or how well you think a question was asked. Although it is not a required policy to do so, I believe that a user should always strongly consider giving a justification for any downvote via a comment, and that apllies to everyone.

Personally, I have felt that your behavior in this forum has been extremely confrontational and I am very sorely tempted to suspend your account right now. I am in the process of moving and have very limited time online, so I can't go through and look at all of your activity at the moment. However, once I do have more time I intend to research your activity very closely, and if I feel that your behavior merits it, I will follow suit with all of the other forums you have indicated and suspend your account.

If you feel that an injustice has been done to you, then alert a moderator by posting in the Meta, as you have done here. If you see a pattern of behavior being repeated across sites, then open your eyes and consider that the problem may be you, and not the rest of the world!

Edited to address a point made in the comments section. My apologies.

Comment: Valid point. I allowed my personal opinions to come out there, and that really wasn't fair or accurate. I believe it is more helpful to the community as a whole if we can see an explanation for downvotes to help provide some guidance on what merits one, but it is certainly not a requirement.

Comment: Tangentially, `I can guarantee that if you have more downvotes than upvotes, or even more than 10% of your total votes are downvotes, you are very likely to have your account suspended` - I have reason to suspect that this is not always a hard rule, or varies site to site; based on some heavily-dowvoting users on SFF. However I don't recall the exact stats (it was discussed on either meta or more likely site chat based on data explorer query), so it's possible that user wasn't above the threshold you listed.

Comment: I edited it a bit more to be more explicit over optionality. Feel free to roll back. +1 since I agree with the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may **vote** any amount of time you wish.

However, deliberately voting on **specific user's** posts  (whether it be 5 or 40 times)  - which it appears you ARE doing based on your own statement `using my right for *downvote a user*` - is what is considered a voting irregularity, since it appears - rightly or wrongly - that you are voting on a post because of its author and not because of the post's quality, which is against both the letter AND the spirit of SE rules.

Note that this rule is generally agnostic to the direction of the vote - you are not allowed to mass-upvote specific users' posts no more than down-vote them.

I would imagine that the suspension rules are more about whether the mods can clearly see from your patterns that you target specific users as opposed to precise # of votes. But I'm not a moderator nor do I play one on TV, so this is just a guess.

If you suspect that someone else is targeting you, the correct thing to do is not to start "retaliating" against them but to complain to the moderators (via meta, or flags).

If someone posts offending comments, you should flag them for moderators.

Comment: Sorry! It is hard for me to find what do you mean. I think if you try to answer the question in one sentence it can help me to find your mean.

Comment: DVK, +1. Persian is well-known on SE network where almost always they violates the rules and, therefore, is often suspended by moderators.